# How to call SQL command in C# Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, odbc

I have an ODBC connection string to a DSN and we are trying to open the connection and run a SQL select statement on the database. The SQL select statement takes 1 parameter `CartID`. When trying to set the value of my parameter passed to the select statement, my browser returns an error that my object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

This is where I am not sure if my variable is not finding my control "Cart Text Box" or if I am not setting the variable correctly.

I have tried change where I am looking to find the control and I have tried writing to the console to check if my variables are being properly set. No luck on either change.

ASPX page markup with button and text boxpanel / Text Box and Button to make call:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ScanCartPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="ScanCartButton">
    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ScanCartTBLabel" runat="server" Text="Scan a Cart"></dx:ASPxLabel>
    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ScanCartTB" runat="server" Width="170px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ScanCartButton" runat="server" 
        Text="Scan Cart" ClientInstanceName="ScanCartID" 
        OnClick="SendScanCartID" AutoPostBack="False" UseSubmitBehavior="false"></dx:ASPxButton>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="NewCartPanel" runat="server">
    <div class="borderd">
        <p>This is a new cart!</p>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

C# code behind:

```
protected void SendScanCartID(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    HiddenField ntsh = (HiddenField)Master.FindControl("nothingToSeeHere");
    Console.WriteLine(ntsh);

    ASPxTextBox cartTextBox = (ASPxTextBox)Master.FindControl("ScanCartTB");

    using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectToPoweredPik"].ConnectionString))
    {
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select Cart_Setup from cart_header where cart_id = ?", con);
        OdbcParameter CartID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@cart_id", OdbcType.Char);
        CartID.Value = cartTextBox.Text;

        con.Open();
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader[0].ToString() != "S")
                {
                    NewCartPanel.Style.Add("display", "none");
                }
                else
                {
                    // show the panel
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The panel should always be shown, unless the [0] value of the reader is S then the panel will hide. Right now I am unable to execute the reader.

Comment: From [FindControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol?view=netframework-4.8) on MSDN: _This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls._

Comment: You could place a null check before your using to throw an exception to be sure you don't do the SQL call... if(cartTextBox == null) {throw new Exception("Unable to find cart textbox.");}

Answer (score 0):

As Steve's comment suggests, you are probably failing to find the textbox control.

You can get the control by navigating parent controls.

```
ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;
ContentPlaceHolder InnerContent = MainContent.FindControl("somecontrolname") as ContentPlaceHolder;
ASPxTextBoxcartTextBox = (ASPxTextBox)InnerContent.FindControl("ScanCartTB");
```

Drilling Into the Appropriate Naming Container...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs#drilling-into-the-appropriate-naming-container